# What will Egypt use its Rafale fighter aircraft for?

Tags: military, egypt

Egypt has [just bought](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-31449564) 24 [Rafale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Rafale) fighter planes.

What kind of threats can these top-notch weapon help Egypt with?
(in particular, threats that less sophisticated weapons would not have been able to handle)

Comment: Do you have a reference that a "less sophisticated" non_Rafale weapon would be otherwise superior, e.g. in TCO?

Comment: @DVK: The question does not imply that... or does it? If it does, how could I fix it to remove that impression?

Comment: if all other angles make Rafale non-inferior, "too sophisticated" isn't a criteria to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main threat Egypt faces *right now* is ISIS affiliated militant groups in neighboring Libya.

However, I suspect the purchase has a lot more to do with diversifying Egypt's fleet, than with helping them deal with imminent threats. Egypt is largely dependent on the US for its defense needs and was put in an awkward position when US aid was suspended after the [2013 coup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Egyptian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat). Although the relationships between the two countries have since been restored, it wouldn't hurt Egypt to have an alternative source of military equipment.

Comment: To add to your point: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-31483631